# How to use promise return TypeError - javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I wrote a Promise function to turn Object of Object to Array of Object:

```javascript
function objectToArray(objectOfObject) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        var newArray = Object.keys(objectOfObject).map(key => {
            let object = objectOfObject[key]
            object['id'] = key
            return object;
        })
        resolve(newArray)
        reject('error')
    })
}
```

So my Resolve will return an Array of object, but how can I return TypeError by using the reject in case of the `objectOfObject` is not an Object of Object, which will caused typeerror I believe?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly was the TypeError you got?

Comment: _which will caused typeerror i believe_...You have to be sure to ask questions otherwise you might get answers based on thoughts **I believe**.

Comment: You mean to verify the parameter available to objectToArray has a parent object?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if...else`

```
function objectToArray (objectOfObject) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof objectOfObject === 'object') {
      var newArray = Object.keys(objectOfObject).map(key => {
        let object = objectOfObject[key]
        object['id'] = key
        return object
      })
      resolve(newArray)
    } else {
      reject(new TypeError())
    }
  })
}
```

or use `try... catch`

```
function objectToArray (objectOfObject) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      var newArray = Object.keys(objectOfObject).map(key => {
        let object = objectOfObject[key]
        object['id'] = key
        return object
      })
      resolve(newArray)
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might want to make the error an instance of `Error`:

```
reject(new Error('error'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function objectToArray (objectOfObject) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof objectOfObject !== 'object') {
      reject(new TypeError())
    }
      var newArray = Object.keys(objectOfObject).map(key => {
        let object = objectOfObject[key]
        object['id'] = key
        return object
      })
      resolve(newArray)

  })
}
```

Comment: Please accept it as answer if you find this as a solution for the stack overflow community and upvote if you find it useful